# How to set multiple formats from environment (font type, text color, font size, etc)?

Tags: formatting, environments, memoir

I want to define an environment with something like a style. That is, when putting any paragraph in that environment, it applies various formats.

For example:

- I want the text to appear in a certain font
- that it has a specific color, defined within the environment and if possible using a command where I define the color
- appear in large size
- appear in bold
- that is not indented
- to add an additional space with respect to the next paragraph
- etc.

I've seen some answers here, and I've written this code:

```
\newenvironment{redtitle}{%
    %\bgroup
    \par
    \fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \noindent \textcolor{red} \textbf
}
{%
    \par %\egroup
}
```

This is the snippet where I try to apply it:

```
\begin{redtitle}
    Some nifty code and stuffz
\end{redtitle}
```

I'm getting this error:

> ! Argument of \textbf  has an extra }. 
> \par  l.230 \begin{redtitle}
> I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything. For example,` \def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce this error. If you simply proceed now, the` \par' that I've just
> inserted will cause me to report a runaway argument that might be the
> root of the problem. But if your `}' was spurious, just type` 2' and
> it will go away.
>
> Runaway argument? ! Paragraph ended before \textbf  was complete. 
> \par  l.230 \begin{redtitle}
> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My
> plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Then, how I can achieve this?

I'm new to LaTeX, so if you see any bad practices or is there a better way to do this, I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: What if you replace `\textbf` with `\bfseries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a couple of errors there. Mainly you are confusing macros which take argument(s) (like `\textcolor` and `\textbf`), and macros which don't (in this case the switches `\color` and `\bfseries`).

`\textcolor` expects two arguments (well, it's a wee bit more complicated than that but let us skirt this issue): the colour and the text to be set in that colour, so usually you have e.g.

```
\textcolor{red}{text which will be printed in red}
```

When you write

```
\textcolor{red} \textbf
```

in TeX's eyes that's pretty much the same as if you had written

```
\textcolor{red}{\textbf}
```

but `\textbf` is by itself a macro which expects an argument, and things will go awfully wrong (as you have experienced).

Long story short: use *switches*: `\bfseries` is a macro telling "make text from here on boldface". You need no braces there: `\bfseries{...}` is useless. Since environments always form a group you need no explicit `\bgroup` and `\egroup` in the environment code.

```
\newenvironment{redtitle}{%
    \par
    \fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
    \noindent
    \color{red}%
    \bfseries
    \ignorespaces
}
{%
 \par
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can customize. I have defined two environemnts. The first one is similar to yours; the second one is a list environment, which is probably more suited to your needs. The style of the paragraph is defined in the `\myenvstyle` macro:

```
\newcommand{\myenvstyle}{%
  \fontfamily{Cochineal-LF}\selectfont\color{mycolor}\Large}
```

while the color is defined via `\definecolor` (this is just one of the many ways of defining a new color with the `xcolor` package):

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0,1}
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\newcommand{\myenvstyle}{%
  \fontfamily{Cochineal-LF}\selectfont\color{mycolor}\Large}

\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
   \myenvstyle\noindent\ignorespaces}
  {\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newenvironment{mylistenv}
  {\list{}{\listparindent 0em%
    \itemindent    \listparindent
    \leftmargin    0pt
    \rightmargin   \leftmargin
    \parsep        0pt}%
  \item\relax\myenvstyle}
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[11]
  \begin{myenv}
    \lipsum[7]
  \end{myenv}  
  \lipsum[11]
  \begin{mylistenv}
    \lipsum[7]
  \end{mylistenv}
  \lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with XeTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%text fonts
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setsansfont{GFS Neohellenic}
%math fonts
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}[version=sansmath]

\newcounter{myenv}
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]% environment name
{% begin code
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\color{blue}%color of body
  \sffamily\mathversion{sansmath}\noindent
  \refstepcounter{myenv}%
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{My Enviroment \themyenv\ #1}}%color of title
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces% if you want to indent jus delete \noindent
}%
{% end code
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
\sum_{i\in I} A_{i}=\prod_{j\in J}B_j
\]
\begin{myenv}
\label{foo}
\lipsum[2]
\[
\sum_{i\in I} A_{i}=\prod_{j\in J}B_j
\]
\end{myenv}
A reference~\ref{foo}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]